# Python: given a list of special tokens, show the distribution of said tokens across sublists of sentences

Tags: python, nltk, frequency

**My problem has two parts, here is the first:**

I have a list of lists like this:

```
big_list = [['i have an apple','i have a pear','i am a monkey', 'tell me about apples'],
['tell me about cars','tell me about trucks','tell me about planes']]
```

I also have a list of words like this:

```
words = ['i','have','monkey','tell','me','about']
```

I want to iterate through **big_list**, checking whether each sublist contains *more than one element from **words** in sequence*. For example, **big_list[0]** would contain **'i have'** from the first and second elements and **'tell me about'** in the final element.

Currently I am trying this at the level of the sublist where i first tokenize all strings in a sublist so that i can iterate through their elements to see where elements from **words** occur:

```
import nltk
example = big_list[0]
example_sentences_tokens = []
for sentence in example:
    example_sentences_tokens.append([token.lower() for token in nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(sentence)])
```

Having access to both original strings and tokenized strings, I check where elements from **words** occur:

```
tuples = []
for sentence, tokenized_sentence in zip(example,example_sentences_tokens):
    tuples.append(tuple((sentence,[token for token in example_sentences_tokens if token in words])))
```

Now, **tuples** is a list of tuples each containing every sentence from **big_list[0]** and all elements of said sentence which exist in **words**.

However, I only want to include tokens existing in **words** if they occur in sequence, not if they occur alone. How can I do this?

**The second part of the problem:**
Finally, once I've identified all instances where a sequence of elements from **words** appears together somewhere in **big_list**, id like to show the frequency of those element sequences in all sublists. So **tell me about** occurs in 100% of **big_list[1]** and 33% of **big_list[0]**. Is there a simple way to show this distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First problem

First of all, when testing your code i had to change your `tuples` content to actually collect common elements between `words` and `tokenized_sentence` (all i got was tuples like (sentence, []) otherwise):

```
tuples.append(((sentence,[token for token in words if token in tokenized_sentence])))
```

To check that we have 2 or more "matches" in sequence, the solution depends on the meaning of your `words`: does their order matter or not?

i.e: if `words = ['i','have','monkey','tell','about', 'me']` (not 'me', 'about'), would `'tell me about apples'` still match? My guess is that it would still match, however I will provide you solutions for both cases.

**In the case that `words`'s tokens order matters**, you can simply check if the matched tokens, separated by a space, is in the examined sentence:

```
tuples = []
for sentence, tokenized_sentence in zip(example, example_sentences_tokens):

    matches = [token for token in words if token in tokenized_sentence]
    sequence = ' '.join(matches) # order of matches matters
    if sequence in sentence:
        tuples.append(((sentence, matches)))

print(tuples)
```

Output:

```
[('i have an apple', ['i', 'have']),
  ('i have a pear', ['i', 'have'])]
```

**In the case that `words`'s tokens order doesn't matter**, you can take the index of the first matching token, and check if the next one in the tokenized sentence is still part of `words`:

```
tuples = []
for sentence, tokenized_sentence in zip(example, example_sentences_tokens):
    #print(sentence, tokenized_sentence)
    #print([token for token in words if token in tokenized_sentence])
    matches = [token for token in words if token in tokenized_sentence]
    i = tokenized_sentence.index(matches[0])
    if tokenized_sentence[i+1] in matches:

        tuples.append(((sentence,matches)))

print(tuples)
```

Output:

```
[('i have an apple', ['i', 'have']),
 ('i have a pear', ['i', 'have']),
 ('tell me about apples', ['tell', 'about', 'me'])]
```

#### Second problem

I imagine you will apply the above procedure on each set of sentences in `big_list`.
What i suggest is to keep a list of the results in `tuples` at each round, along with the index of the list of sentences in `big_list` examinanted: in this way you can keep track of all matches combinations, and work your way towards computing the percentanges of occurrences based in the index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

The word order doesn't matter.

Just one follow up question on your post that I shouldve specified; in the output of tuples how can i join all of the elements which existed in words and are now in your matches variable into one string if they occur next to each other?

so for example, the sentence, "i have a dog" should become ["i have"], but "i have a dog and i am happy" should become ["i have", "i"]

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct if you think it is? To answer this followup question, I would do something like if ' '.join(tuple[1]) in tuple[0]: tuple[1] = ' '.join(tuple[1])